# Read a Date from text file and compare with current Date in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I pipelined date to a text file through Powershell. Now i need to compare the date in the text file with the current date. I am unable to figure it out. Pls help.

```
(get-date).AddDays(3) | Out-File -FilePath c:\time.txt
$deadline = Get-Content -Path C:\time.txt
$currenttime = Get-Date
IF ($currenttime -lt $deadline) 
{Write-host "Continue Working"}
Else 
{Write-Host "Your Logic is Wrong"}
```

I do not get any output. Pls help.

Comment: Assuming your file will only contain just ***one*** date, you can do this: `$deadline = (Get-Content -Path C:\time.txt) -as [datetime]`

Comment: its just as Santiago says. You need to either compare it as a string, or date. In this case it should be date as its most logical.

Comment: ... and add `-NoNewline` to `Out-File` otherwise `Get-Content` will return you an array instead of one string.

Comment: Agree with Lieven, forgot to mention that you may have to trim the results of the content if not supplying the `-NoNewLine` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You should compare date with date.

```
(get-date).AddDays(3).ToString() | Out-File -FilePath time.txt
$deadline = [datetime](Get-Content -Path time.txt) 
$currenttime = Get-Date
IF ($currenttime -lt $deadline) {Write-host "Continue Working"} Else  {Write-Host "Your Logic is Wrong"}
```